# Help with proving an equation factorial-time complexity

Tags: factorial

I've been recently asked by one of my friends to prove an equation but still, I'm confused how to get it started tho.

log(n!)= θ(nlog(n))

Does anyone know how to help?
I'll be very grateful if someone comes to reply to my issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\log(n!)=\sum_{k=1}^n\log{k}$  Use a Riemann sum.

Comment: And now you just go for a worst case scenario, so you estimate every term by the upper bound $\log(n)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$O(\log{(n!)})$$$$=O(\log{(n(n-1)(n-2)...(2)(1))})$$$$=O(\log{(n)}+\log{(n-1)}+\log{(n-2)}+...+\log{(2)}+\log{(1)})$$$$=O(n\log{(n))}$$
As $n$ logarithms are added, we have a worst case time complexity of $O(n\log{(n))}$.

Comment: Thank you, sir.

Comment: Will you accept my answer?

Comment: Yes, surely. Thanks again.